# Getting an access to list, which is a field in the class

Tags: c#

I am implementing my own ORM using c# and I need to keep all methods and fields as general as possible.

I have declared a random class. This class has a couple of fields and one of them is a list (class Person and list of neighbours)).

I want to get the field's value of certain class instances. This is what I do to get the values of fields: function (object o).

I can easily get the value of this person age, but since "Invoke" function returns "object", I cannot iterate over the list of neighbours.

```
class Person {
    private int _age {get; set; }
    private LinkedList<Neighbour> _neighbours {get; set;};
   ....
}
public void function(object o){
    Type type = o.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
    {
        MethodInfo strGetter = prp.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
        var val =  strGetter.Invoke(o, null);
        // Here I want to iterate over "val", which contains value of the field (in my case: _neighbours)
    }
}
public int main(){
     function(new Person(/* age */, /*some LinkedList*/));
}
```

Converting it as:

```
    LinkedList<object> val = (LinkedList<object>) str.Getter.Invoke(0, null)
```

doesn't work since it says that it cannot convert type 'object' into 'Neighbour'.

How can I iterate over that set?

Comment: What about checking what's inside that object before trying to cast it into something else? Just set a breakpoint there.

Comment: Usually simply casting it to a non-generic `IList` or `ICollection` is your friend in this kind of reflection-based code... but: watch out, this kind of reflection can be relatively expensive if used a lot; how much is "a lot" depends on context

Comment: LinkedList<Neighbour> data = val as LinkedList<Neighbour>

Comment: I'm curious.  Why do you want to write an ORM (see Sam Saffron's https://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM)?  And why do you want to write one that _"keep(s) all methods and fields as general as possible."_?  The best ORM's are pretty strongly typed.  Oh, and if you have a function named (lower case) `function`, please don't hire me as a maintenance programmer

Comment: str.Getter.Invoke(0, null) -> is this a typo? (your code from above seems to mention str.Getter.Invoke(o, null) )